# Table unnecessarily starting from next page in latex

Tags: tables, pdftex, texniccenter

How can i stop my table in latex to start unnecessarily from next page leaving a huge space in previous page? How can i force to start just after the heading. Please help, here is my code:
i am using packages:

```
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption},
\usepackage{float}
```

and the code for my table is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{natbib}

% Load up special logo commands.
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}
% Package for formatting URLs.
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Syntax summary}
\textbf{Basic regular expression syntax}
\vspace{1.5mm}
\hrule
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{| l| l }
$.$ & Matches any character.\\ 
$*$ & Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
$+$ & Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
$?$ & Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.\\
$( )$ & Groups a subpattern. The repetition and alternation operators apply to the preceding subpattern.\\
$|$ & Alternation.\\
$[ ]$ & Delimit a set of characters. Ranges are specified as [x-y].\\
\textasciicircum & Anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string. Only when first.\\
\$ & Anchor the pattern to the end of the string. Only when last.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\hrule
\vspace{1.5mm}
\textbf{Advanced regular expression syntax.}
\vspace{1.5mm}
\hrule
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{| l| l }
${m}$ & Matches m instances of the previous pattern item.\\
${m}?$ & Matches m instances of the previous pattern item.\\ 
${m,}$ & Matches m or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
${m,}?$ & Matches m or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\ 
${m,n}$ & Matches m through n instances of the previous pattern item.\\
${m,n}?$ & Matches m through n instances of the previous pattern item.\\ 
$*?$ & Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\ 
$+?$ & Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\ 
$??$ & Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.\\ 
$(?:re)$ & Groups a subpattern, re, but does not capture the result.\\
$(?=re)$ & Positive look-ahead. Matches the point where re begins.\\
$(?!re)$ & Negative look-ahead. Matches the point where re does not begin.\\
$(?abc)$ & Embedded options, where abc is any number of option letters.\\
$[: :]$ & Delimits a character class within a bracketed expression.\\ 
$[. .]$ & Delimits a collating element within a bracketed expression.\\
$[= =]$ & Delimits an equivalence class within a bracketed expression.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I tried `[!ht]`, `[!htp]` or `[htpb]`, but nothing of that sort works instead the table vanishes. So please help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Generally, if you don't want huge spaces on the page, don't use `H` because it defeats one of LaTeX's main mechanisms for producing nice page breaks: the ability to float (move) figures and tables around the document.

Comment: actually i am making a report and have a long code but my problem is the table starts from next page when there is already space left in the previous page

Comment: what to use instead of [H]

Comment: removing this[H] the table itself is vanishing..please help !!

Comment: Are you sure the table didn't just "float" to another place in the document? TeX tries to find the best spot *near* where you inserted the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`. If you don't want the table to float, don't use that environment.

Comment: it came under another section where i did not want it, this i noticed later

Comment: You have used `[H]`:  the only purpose of that is to say that you don't want the table to float _even if it makes a horrible page break leaving large white space_,

Comment: so what can i use instead of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caption + No headings + No floating = Smells like a list to me, rather than a table.

Any desired styling/indentation can be added using built-in commands or a package for modifying lists such as [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

This solution can break across pages, unlike a standard `tabular` environment (especially unlike a `tabular` wrapped in a `table` environment).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item{$.$} Matches any character.
\item{$*$} Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.
\item{$+$} Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.
\item{$?$} Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.
\item{$(\,)$} Groups a subpattern. The repetition and alternation operators apply to the preceding subpattern.
\item{$|$} Alternation.
\item{$[\,]$} Delimit a set of characters. Ranges are specified as [x-y].
\item{\textasciicircum} Anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string. Only when first.
\item{\$} Anchor the pattern to the end of the string. Only when last.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's one possible way of achieving a nicer alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}\def\Item#1{\item{\makebox[8pt]{#1}}}
\Item{$.$} Matches any character.
\Item{$*$} Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.
\Item{$+$} Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.
\Item{$?$} Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.
\Item{$(\,)$} Groups a subpattern. The repetition and alternation operators apply to the preceding subpattern.
\Item{$|$} Alternation.
\Item{$[\,]$} Delimit a set of characters. Ranges are specified as [x-y].
\Item{\textasciicircum} Anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string. Only when first.
\Item{\$} Anchor the pattern to the end of the string. Only when last.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are of course innumerable other ways to do it.

Comment: but i want it like a table and that too without the problem it is causing that- leaving extra spaces in previous page starting from a new page,is there no way to sort it?

Comment: @Soumyashree as mentioned in the comments, let the table float if you really want it to be a table. But as I said, there's really no reason for it to be a table.

Comment: @PaulGessler -- the start of the text for the various `\item`s is very ragged.  if these were uniformly indented to the same starting point as the second line of the two-line description, it would look more like a table.  the `tabbing` environment might be an alternative.

Comment: @barbarabeeton as mentioned in my answer, there are many ways to customize the styling/alignment, which I did not cover here. The point of the post was that it really shouldn't be done as a table in the first place.

Comment: @PaulGessler -- i agree with the contention that this shouldn't really be done as a table.  i was only trying to point out that the raggedy appearance of the result you show wouldn't likely be found attractive enough for someone to take the answer seriously.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, added one of many possibilities here.